# Only display the first tier of categories

Tags: categories

I'm looking to only display the top level parent categories on my Template, but unfortunately, everything I try seems to error out and still display all of the children categories as well.

My current code looks like the following:

```
  {% set categories = craft.categories.group('discounts') %}
        {% for category in categories.all() %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter `elements` based on their hierarchy level with the `level` attribute

```
{% for category in categories.level(1).all() %}
```

Will only show top tier categories

```
{% for category in categories.level(2).all() %}
```

only all the first tier children of all first tier categories (so tier 2) and so on.

*Additional note*

You can also search for descendants elements

```
element.getDescendants(1) //<-- include the level based on the parents level
```

With the parameter  `1` it is the same as

```
element.getChildren()
```